# Laravel Ajax "GET" keeps resulting in 500 Error

Tags: ajax, laravel

I have already searched the web but most 500 Errors tend to be for the "POST" ajax type.
I am trying to get some data from my server using Ajax method.

My script is as follows

```
  <script type="text/javascript">             
       function getuserinfo(id) {            
           var userID = id;
           console.log(userID);
           if(userID) {
            $.ajax({
                url: '/guestinfo/ajax/'+userID,
                type: "GET",
                dataType: "json",
                success:function() {                        
                     $('#infoModal').modal('show');  
                }                  
            });
        }

    };

 </script>
```

My Route is as follows

```
Route::get('/guestinfo/ajax/{guest_id}','Controller\Control@getInfo');
```

My controller is as follows

```
public function getInfo($id)
{

    if($request->ajax())
    {
        $guestid = $id;

        $guest = Guest::where('id', '=', $guestid)->firstOrFail();

        return json_encode($guest);
    }

}
```

[Error log from console](https://i.stack.imgur.com/DcnJo.png)

Any help or guidance will be appreciated.

Comment: We can help if you submit the error log.

Comment: I have now edited  and added error log

Comment: Please see last log file. `$ROOT/storage/xxxx-xx-xx-laravel.log`.

Comment: Have you tried commenting out everything in your controller method and just returning $id?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You should use return `response()->json($guest);` to return json data instead of `return json_encode($guest);`

And the error is because of the `$request` is not defined that should be an instance of `Request $request` in your method.

```
public function getInfo(Request $request, $id)
{

    if($request->ajax())
    {
        $guestid = $id;

        $guest = Guest::where('id', '=', $guestid)->firstOrFail();

        return response()->json($guest);
    }

}
```

Answer (score 0):

You should be checking your log files so you can actually see what is causing the `500` error, always.

Just by going off of your code that you have pasted you are trying to use an undefined variable as an object:

```
$request->ajax()
```

That variable, `$request`, is undefined in the scope of that method.